# Ubuntu 16.04 shuts down on it's own

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have the following problem:
I have a 32-Bit Pc with an AMD-Athlon X2 processor. It's harddisk has two partitions. One of them has Windows 7 and the other one has Ubuntu 16.04. 
The Windows 7 partition works fine. However, the Ubuntu partition ramdonly shots down itself since a few days ago.
The last thing I did before the problems began was install chromium and IG:DM (Instagram Direct Messenger) and resolve a critical problem with Firefox. Afterwards, it shotsdown itself even while I work only with a terminal and/or a ZSNES emulator.
Using `fcsk` did not solved the problem. 
I searched into the log files and I didn't find a clue. The only thing couldn't test was if upgrading the kernel from a 4.x.x version to a 5.0.8 version would solve the problem, because Ubuntu shots down itself even while compiling the kernel. Also, I don't know if backing up my Firefox configuration and then uninstalling Firefox and Chromium and re-installing Firefox is the solution. I cannot say the problem is the PC's fan because if it were for that, Windows 7 also would shotdown itself.

Also, I don't know if the following is related: in Windows 7 ramdomly my Internet Connection is interrupted once in a day since my parents changed the Internet Service provider and it's solved using the Window's Problem Solver.

Given the description above, do you have any ideas of what could cause the Ubuntu shotdown? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it an orderly shut-down, as if done manually? Does `dmesg -H|less` show any relevant log records for the time of the shut-down?

Comment: No. It doesn't say nothing relevant.

Comment: Thanks to all for the concern. I already solved this problem... cleaning my PC. It is ironic but true. For some reason, Linux is more sensitive with the PC's heat than Windows and that made me confused.